# Wh-movement Question

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, movement, wh-words

For wh-movements, I always think of what the sentence would have looked like if it wasn't a question (e.g. for sentence "which promise did he not keep?", I would think that the original sentence would be "he did not keep (which promise)" and move "which promise" and "did" for wh-movement)

However, I don't understand how this sentence works: "which canvas appears to have been painted with a red paint?". I figured that the original sentence would be "The/A canvas appears to have been painted with a read paint". How do I make an wh-movement for these type of sentences?

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence for the question “Which canvas appears to have been painted with a red paint?” is “This/That canvas appears to have been painted with a red paint”, and the answer would be “This one/canvas” or “that one/canvas”.

The reason why that sentence has no `does` is that it is the subject noun phrase (NP) that is being questioned. When, say, an object is substituted by a wh-NP, then that `does` (or anything like `do`/`did`/`is`/`must`, etc.) stands *between* the wh-NP and the subject NP, e.g.:

> “He reads *The New York Times* every morning.” – “*The New York Times*” is the object, if we put a question to it, we get:
> “*What* `does` he read every morning?” – `does` stands between the object “what” and the subject “he”.

But in the case of your canvas sentence when the wh-NP and the subject NP are the same, no `do`/`does`/`did` is “extracted”<sup>1</sup> from the predicate verb, and the verb remains as it is in the original declarative sentence. One more example:

> “My father likes coffee.” – “My father” is the subject NP. By asking “whose?” we put a question to the subject NP, so no `does` is extracted, “likes” remains as it is:
> “Whose father likes coffee?” – direct word order.

In short, when the question is put to the subject noun phrase, the word order remains direct, like in the original declarative sentence, no `do`/`does`/`did` is added to the sentence, and only what's questioned is substituted for a wh-whord.

---

<sup>1</sup> by `do`/`does`/`did` “extraction” I mean the transformation of the synthetic verb forms into analytic ones, e.g.: *come* → *do come*, *comes* → *does come*, *came* → *did come*.